# What happens to processes when the kernel is stopped in Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a bit of code in Jupyter Notebook that creates a `multiprocessing.Pool`, does some computation with that pool using `starmap`, then closes the pool.

```
p = Pool(2)
vals = p.starmap(pFunc, ls)
p.close()
```

If I restart the kernel through Jupyter Notebook while it's running `vals = p.starmap(pFunc, ls)`, what happens to these processes?